# How to calculate Holiday + Weekends in PHP

Tags: php

I have a date say '22/12/2022'

I want to show such that
(22/12/2022 + 3 days)

That is (25/12/2022)

but 25 is Holiday also 25 falls in Sunday
I want to print date as (27/12/2022)

since 26 also a holiday now I want to show
date as (28/12/2022)

if 28 or 29 is also holiday or falls in saturday and sunday push the date to other days with no holiday or weekends

Can anyone help me with  a code?

```
$startDate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date.' + 1 days'));
$newDate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date.' + 3 days'));

$weekEnds = $this->getWeekEnds($startDate, $newDate);
$holidayArray = 'Query that will fetch Holiday between $startDAte and $newDate';
```

I'm lacking in logic..

Comment: Please provide examples of input and output to corroborate what you want

Comment: I have provided the example